# Heat maps using Google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I am trying to create a heat map using Google Maps API. I am getting the map but not the heat values on the co-ordinates. Given below ids the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&sensor=true">
      
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

   function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(8.881928, 76.592758),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&sensor=true&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
window.onload = loadScript;
 </script>

<script>
var heatMapData = [
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(8.8678, 76.5623 },
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(9.5674, 77.5623)},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(10.7821, 78.447)},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(12.4523, 79.443)},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.441)},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.439)},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.435)},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.447)},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.445)},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.441)},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.437)},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.435)}
];
  
var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
  data: heatMapData
});
heatmap.setOptions({radius: heatmap.get('20')});
heatmap.setMap(map);

</script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the screenshot of the output. Could anyone help me in this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#JSHeatMaps), you should be passing an array of `google.maps.LatLng` objects to the `HeatmapLayer` as `data`.

Try this:

```js
var heatMapData = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(8.8678, 76.5623),
    new google.maps.LatLng(9.5674, 77.5623),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.7821, 78.447),
    new google.maps.LatLng(12.4523, 79.443),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.441),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.439),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.435),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.447),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.445),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.441),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.437),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.435)
];
```

Also, you need to load the `google.maps.visualization` library by adding `&libraries=visualization` to the end of the URL when you include the Google Maps API.

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/EBQQH/**

Comment: @AravindAsok Glad to help! If this answered your question splendidly, please consider giving me a big green checkmark! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are forget to put the ending bracket here
{location: new google.maps.LatLng(8.8678, 76.5623_ _ _},

that is the problem